# canonical rel tag and 301 redirect loop?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, canonical-url

I'm working with an e-commerce platform and I'm not sure about the behaviour of the canonical rel tag after changing some URL keys.

This is the specific situation:

- `old_url.html` -> redirects to -> `new_url.html`
- The platform adds a canonical rel tag that points to `old_url.html`

wouldn't that keep the search engines in a loop? Like going from **old** to **new** to **old** to **new** etc.?

Comment: The search engines are likely to ignore the canonical tag in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Sure does sound like it. Your 301 redirect says `new_url.html` is the correct page for that content but your canonical URLs say it is `old_url.html`. That's a loop if I ever saw one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a loop. But I doubt any search engine would be dumb enough to actually go looping through this. But you should be aware that a search engine might regard it strange that each URL says that the other one is actually the right place to go to.

I cannot imagine a valid use case for a setup like this - you (or the platform maintainer) should decide for one one of the URLs and have the other 301-redirect there.